# How to generate column based on order id in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have two tables: `customerTable` and `orderTable` that are shown below. I need to generate `order` column dynamically.

**CustomerTable**

```
custId CustName
01     Suresh
02     Ramesh
```

**OrderTable**

```
custId  OrderId 
01      011
01      012
```

need output as like :

```
custId Order1 Order2
01     011    012
```

Here if order is multiple times for each customer then columns will be added dynamically.

If custId = 01 has 011,012,013,014...... has many order then table will be like

```
custId order1  order2 order3 order4 order5 order6 ...... many oder N columns 
01     011       012   013   014    015    06     ....... 0N..
```

Comment: Check out the feature called pivoting. It does just that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Do you know the total or maximum number of orders a customer can have?  If not, this isn't a good approach; generally SQL's designed around the concept of query results having a fixed number of columns with a variable number of rows.

Comment: @GurV user mentioned he needs order id dynamicaly and then after that pivot will come into picture

Comment: there are no fixed columns for order , it will be multiples , i am working with complex queries , need better solution so i can work with that , is PIVOT better solution, or is there any solution except this pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this dynamically like this:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
declare @cols as nvarchar(max)

set @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.OrderId)
            FROM OrderTable c
            order by 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @sql = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(OrderId) + ' as Order' + convert(varchar,row_number() over (order by OrderId))
            from (
                select distinct OrderId 
                FROM OrderTable
            ) t
            order by 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @sql = 'SELECT custId, ' + @sql + ' from 
            (
                select *
                from OrderTable
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(OrderId)
                for OrderId in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
exec(@sql)
```

Produces:

[image]

To be noted here is that, it works correctly for one custId as the columns are aligned based on the the OrderId in the pivoted result.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called pivoting. See the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

A simple example taken from the link above:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT
    DaysToManufacture,
    AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost
FROM Production.Product
GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;
```

Results in:

```
DaysToManufacture | AverageCost
----------------------------------------
0                 | 5.0885
1                 | 223.88
2                 | 359.1082
4                 | 949.4105
```

These are rows in the source table grouped, no pivoting done yet. By pivoting, you turn the values of the rows in column #1 into columns, and the values of the rows in column #2 get 'rotated' and appear as one row. The SQL to do that is the following:

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT
    'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
    [0],
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DaysToManufacture,
        StandardCost 
    FROM
        Production.Product
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    AVG(StandardCost)
    FOR DaysToManufacture IN
    (
        [0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]
    )
) AS PivotTable;
```

This results in output such as:

```
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days | 0      | 1      | 2        | 3    | 4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AverageCost                    | 5.0885 | 223.88 | 359.1082 | NULL | 949.4105
```